# Speeding up vectorization in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

First question, sorry if I mess something up.

I'm doing a classification project involving 1600 unique text documents over 90 labels. Many of these documents are research papers, so you can imagine the feature set is quite large - well over a million.

My problem is that vectorizing is taking *forever*. I understand it won't be fast given my data, but the time it takes is becoming impractical. I took the advice from the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195699/sklearn-how-to-speed-up-a-vectorizer-eg-tfidfvectorizer) and it doesn't seem to have helped - I'm imagining the optimizations the answerer suggests are already incorporated into scikit-learn.

Here's my code, using the adjusted stemmed vectorizer functions:

```
%%timeit

vect = StemmedCountVectorizer(min_df=3, max_df=0.7, max_features=200000, tokenizer=tokenize,
        strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
        ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words='english')

vect.fit(list(xtrain) + list(xvalid))
xtrain_cv = vect.transform(xtrain)
xvalid_cv = vect.transform(xvalid)
```

The tokenizer references this function:

```
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if i not in string.punctuation]
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if all(j.isalpha() or j in string.punctuation for j in i)]
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if '/' not in i]
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems
```

The `%%timeit` report:

```
24min 16s ± 28.2 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is there anything that's obviously slowing me down? Any obvious inefficiencies would be good to know about. I'm thinking about reducing my n-gram range to (1,2) as I don't think I'm getting too many useful 3-gram features, but besides that I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint - what do you mean by "the other solution"? If you're referencing the default vectorizers: they are extremely slow as well. That's what motivated my original search for optimization solutions. Unfortunately, I just now started using `%%timeit` so I don't have a time report, but I'm running it now.

Comment: the posted stack overflow link

Comment: oh, well that's the code I'm currently using when I call `StemmedCountVectorizer()` but my issue is that it's still very slow. I'm doing both a countvectorizer and tfidfvectorizer for testing purposes, and the `StemmedCountVectorizer()` finished, but the `StemmedTfidfVectorizer()` was still running when I woke up this morning, meaning it was going for at least three hours.

Comment: You are doing tri-gram, that's why. You should be amazed it works within 30 minutes.

Comment: @Mai - switching to (1,2) and running now. Still running slow but we'll see what the `%%timeit` results are. Do you know of any other optimizations?

Answer (score 2):

1600 text documents is not really that big, so it should be much faster. Some advises:

1) To profile your code, use [cProfile and ptats](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html). You'll see what exact steps are slow.

2) n-grams have huge complexity. Bi-grams are usually ok, tri-grams start being very cumbersome. Use a "smarter" solution. Why not the gensim [phraser](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) ?

3) using `in` operator doesn't do well with lists (because it tests each element of the list), but does well with sets (because of the underlying hash function). You should consider strings, like `string.punctuation`, as lists. Just convert it to a set.

4) Factorise your `tokenize` function (multiple loops on `token`) if you can.

5) If it is not fast enough, use multi threading.